# What rendering API does Rage use on PC?

Tags: pc, rage

Is Rage for PC using OpenGL or DirectX? From all the Radeon card troubles, I would presume the former, but I would like to be sure.

If you have the game, you can tell which one it is by by opening the *exe* with the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and checking whether it links to opengl32.dll or d3dx.dll. Also, [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) can determine the loaded DLLs for a running game.

Comment: It's rendering API, not graphics engine, which is Id Tech 5.

Comment: My apologies. I've re-edited the title - is that more accurate?

Comment: Thanks. I also added one way of telling which one the game is using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RAGE uses the Id Tech 5 engine, which is based of on OpenGL.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rage_%28video_game%29)

> Rage is a first-person shooter video game by id Software which was released on October 4, 2011 in North America. It uses the company's new OpenGL based id Tech 5 engine

Here's the .exe from Dependency Walker:
[image]

Comment: Id Tech 5 runs on XBox 360, so it has to be able to use (a variant of) DirectX, as well.

Comment: @DonReba Sorry, was a bit fast, updated it with a print screen from Dependency Walker.

Comment: @DonReba, they sort of programmed D3D on the XBox. See this [article](http://www.maximumpc.com/article/features/e3_2008_the_john_carmack_interview_rage_id_tech_6_doom_4_details_and_more) (search for OpenGL on the page).

Comment: It actually uses *both*, judging by the screen shot. OpenGL for the rendering and DirectX for input. But then, I assume the question asker confused DirectX with Direct3D anyway ...